# Regarding comparison of a real number with a complex integral.

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we have the following equation:

$\mu \leq \int_{C}f(z)dz$, where $C$ is a contour over which the above integral converges.

Now $\mu$ is real. So should we consider the real part of the above integral for the bound.

Alternatively, can we integrate over the restriction of the contour over the real line.

Also, say $\mu=f(z)$ should we take real part of $f(z)$ or the restriction of $f(z)$ on real line?

Comment: You can say $|\mu| \leq |\int {f(z) dz}| \leq \int {|f(z)|dz}$. Furthur simpification can be made depending on the function $f(z)$

Comment: thanks for the comment.....what is your opinion on the other question about the equality?

Comment: Something with $\le$ is an inequality, not an equation. I don't think there is an accepted meaning for $\alpha\le\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ complex. And $\alpha=\beta$ certainly can't be true unless $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the same complex number. What would possess you to write something like $1=1+i$? That's antithetical to the meaning of equality.

Comment: In many physics applications, equations like $\cos(\omega t)$ is nothing but real part of a rotating complex phasor in argand plane. Then even though the phasor is given by $\exp(j\phi(t))$, we get only the $\cos(\phi(t))$ by taking the real part. Such situations arise often in applied math.

Comment: @Hamza I've seen such use of complex numbers/phasors. Perhaps I would be able to help you if you could elaborate the problem further like from where does it arise etc.

Comment: @zed11....$\mu$ is the step size of a newton descent algorithm. I am investigating the range of step-sizes for which my algorithm converges. To cut a long story short, the calculation for the bound finally boils down to expectation of a  complex random variable in the numerator divided by a expectation of a real random variable in denominator. That is how I am getting a complex number in numerator.